# Need to create a DSN for Oracle connection and TNS file

Tags: oracle, odbc

I am a new on Oracle and trying to connect to the Oracle database from my desktop. I have the TNS information and created a TNS file called `tnsanames.ora`.

What location do I copy that file to?

I know I need to create a DSN for Oracle connection but when I open the ODBC Data Source Administrator, I don't see any drivers for Oracle. When I click Add and the Create New Data Source window appears, I only see SQL Server, MySQL, etc... but no Oracle.

What am I missing?

Comment: you dont use odbc to connect to oracle. Oracle supplies their own client with drivers to connect.  You do need SQL Plus or a similar GUI tool.  What operating system, what Oracle version, what have you installed

Comment: I assume you mean DSN (data source name) rather than DNS (domain name system).  Have you installed the Oracle client on your machine?  Did you install the ODBC driver as part of that installation?  Are you using 32- or 64-bit Windows?  Did you install a 32- or 64-bit client?

Comment: It should be in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/ unless you created TNS_ADMIN environment variable (assuming Windows OS). Structure of the file is very picky so if you created it manually as it seems, I hope you did it correctly. :)

Comment: You have two ODBC Data Source Administrators: 32 bit and 64 bit. The architecture has to match the architecture of your installed Oracle Client. Did you install ODBC drivers at installation? They are not installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a tns ora file connect to a oracle database, you need an oracle client installed, where the file actually goes.

You can place the TNS ora file in ORACLE HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN or a relevant windows location where your client is installed.

Client: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html